# Мигает скроллбар

Tags: django, bootstrap

кастомизирую админпанет adminlte и при создании формы для django, и вводе в неё текст постоянно мигает скроллбар, подскажите что делать ?

На рисунке видно что вправа есть скроллбар, но если ввести ещё один симво, окроллбар исчезнет, а потом опять появится

Comment: отредактируйте пожалуйста ваш вопрос, а то не понятно где именно у вас проблема. Допускаю что вы не прикрепили скриншот

Answer (score 0):

Помогло добавить в стиль overflow-y: scroll;
и перезагрузить стили ctrl shift r